# PHP Get sum of each month's sales from two arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays where the keys are the same, one with the month/year and the other with the values:

Array 1:

```php
['Apr 2023', 'Mar 2023', 'Apr 2023', 'Apr 2023', 'Feb 2023']
```

Array 2:

```php
[833.00, 223.00, 829.00, 220.00, 498.00]
```

I need to find the totals for each month:

Apr 2023: `1882.00`

Mar 2023: `223.00`

Feb 2023: `498.00`

I have tried combining into one multidimensional array and then using array_reduce, but I keep getting type errors. I have tried writing a series of functions to step through the data, but I can't figure out how to compare the month/year with the previous entry. It seems that I'm missing an obvious answer... Any thoughts?
And to those who might say that this has previously been answered multiple times, I have been searching the web and SO for several hours and haven't come up with anything close.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the type error you're getting? Please include the example code you're having trouble with for this to be a more complete question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the `months` array, and use that index to get the amount from the other array, and add that to the month's sum. Live example at https://3v4l.org/uItTB

```
<?php

$months = [
    '2023-04',
    '2023-03',
    '2023-04',
    '2023-04',
    '2023-02',
];

$amounts = [
    833,
    223,
    829,
    220,
    498
];

$sums = [];

foreach($months as $i => $month) {
    if (!isset($sums[$month])) {
        $sums[$month] = 0;
    }
    
    $sums[$month] += $amounts[$i];
}

var_dump($sums);
```

outputs:

```
array(3) {
  ["2023-04"]=>
  int(1882)
  ["2023-03"]=>
  int(223)
  ["2023-02"]=>
  int(498)
}
```

Note that the main functionality in the loop is just the line `$sums[$month] += $amounts[$i];`. The `if (!isset($sums[$month]))` before that is purely to avoid a PHP warning about the array index being undefined before trying to add a value to it - `Warning: Undefined array key "2023-04"`. You could remove that conditional and it would still function the same. And if you wanted to suppress the warning too, you could use the `@` operator: `@$sums[$month] += $amounts[$i];`.